# SystemVerilog: Data types and display of default size of data type

Tags: system-verilog

How can I display the size of a 'real' (or 'float') in system verilog?

`$bits` can display size of int, shortint, longint, time, integer, etc. but cannot do the same for a real.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot select individual bits of a real number, nor is there any other construct that requires to know the number of bits in a real number. So SystemVerilog does not need to provide a way to tell you.

Answer (score 0):

`real` is not a *real* verilog type. It is intended for testbench or for analog calculations, not for design. Therefore it has no bit size associated with it.

However from lrm:

> The real data type is the same as a C double. The shortreal data type is the same as a C float. The
> realtime declarations shall be treated synonymously with real declarations and can be used
> interchangeably. Variables of these three types are collectively referred to as real variables.

And there is a function which converts real to bits:

> **$realtobits** converts values from a real type to a 64-bit vector representation of the real number.

and corresponding

> **$bitstoreal** converts a bit pattern created by $realtobits to a value of the real type

So, you can assume that the size of real is 64 bits after conversion to bits.